# Making multiple instances of a Class without manually typing every one in

Tags: python

In the following code, I have made a class that plots a point:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random 

class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        X = random.randint(0,50)
        Y = random.randint(0,50)

        plt.plot(X, Y,'o')
```

What I am wondering is that how can you make many instances of this class without manually typing every single one in.

Comment: It makes no sense to create many instances of that class because that would just result in the same point being plotted over and over. What is the aim of this?

Comment: This is just an example, my main question here is how to make multiple instances of a Class without manually typing every one in

Comment: You instantiate a class by like `p = Point()`. I have a problem understanding the "manually typing in" part of the question.

Comment: Because if I want to make 100 instances of the class then it might just get a little annoying to type every 100 of them out, thus why I want my code to do it for me. And also making many instances won't result in the same plot being plotted over and over again @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it will result in a scatter of a bunch of random points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Point() for _ in range(100)]
```

gives you a list of 100 instances of class Point.

Answer (score -1):

First, we'll remove the plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random 

class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 50)
        self.y = random.randint(0, 50)
```

Next, let's define a function that returns a list of `n` points:

```py
def getNPoints(n):
    points = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        points.append(Point())
    return points
```

Finally, do whatever you want with those points:

```
points = getNPoints(10)
for point in points:
    plt.plot(point.x, point.y, 'o')
```

Putting it all together:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random 

class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 50)
        self.y = random.randint(0, 50)

def getNPoints(n):
    points = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        points.append(Point())
    return points

points = getNPoints(10)
for point in points:
    plt.plot(point.x, point.y, 'o')
```